# Can Anyone provide an example of RAW SQL for SELECTING posts by 2 or more tags

Tags: sql

I need a RAW SQL, as I am working from different platform with WordPress Database.

When I run `example.com/tag/first+second`, WordPress runs a query `SELECT post_id, meta_key, meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id IN (10649,7783,6336,4556,3938)`

Where did this get the post IDs? I am only guessing.
I do have certain thoughts about it, but first want to see if someone knows.

Here is the query I have built when getting posts by SINGLE tag:

```
SELECT `wp_posts`.`ID`, `wp_posts`.`post_name`, `wp_posts`.`post_title`, `wp_posts`.`post_date`, `wp_posts`.`post_content` , DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),post_date) as days_ago 
FROM `wp_posts` 
    INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships
        ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) 
    INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy 
        ON (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
    INNER JOIN wp_terms 
        ON (wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = wp_terms.term_id)
WHERE 1=1
    AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'post_tag'
    AND wp_terms.slug SOUNDS LIKE 'Hennessy'
    AND wp_terms.slug SOUNDS LIKE 'VS' 
    AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
    AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

thanks.

Comment: "Different platform"; you are working with the WordPress database, though?

Comment: @Mike Yes, I would say MYSQL database. As I am not using Wordpress Database abstraction classes

Comment: But you are using the WordPress database *schema*, right?

Comment: @Mike  Yes you are right the Wp db schema

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be catching wrong query. Dumping SQL for such URL (via `posts_request` filter) get me this:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.* 
FROM wp_posts  
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) 
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships AS tt1 ON (wp_posts.ID = tt1.object_id) 
WHERE 1=1  
AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (93) AND tt1.term_taxonomy_id IN (94) AND wp_posts.ID IN (
                    SELECT object_id
                    FROM wp_term_relationships
                    WHERE term_taxonomy_id IN (93,94)
                    GROUP BY object_id HAVING COUNT(object_id) = 2
                ) ) 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' 
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

In any case see `WP_Query->get_posts()` method, which handles turning query variables into SQL. There is a **lot** of code there and a lot of it was changed in 3.1, so it's a little hard for me to pinpoint where multiple tags are handled.

Comment: Yes you are right I have somewhat, slightly different query, but even from the one you pointed, I am not able to use it for multiple "tag" selection

Comment: @simple does URL `example.com/tag/first+second` fetch what you want? Just hook into `posts_request` and dump query it generates, as I did. Need help with that?

Comment: @Rast it does fetch, but it runs a query similar to `"SELECT post_id, meta_key, meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id IN (10649,7783,6336,4556,3938)"`, But what I need is to get those post_id s! I also check them against Soundex, so the case just get's a little funnier! Any thought on how to dump all the queries wordpress executes per one Request ?

Comment: @simple That query is not even query for posts, it is query for custom fields. I am not sure what it has to do with anything, as above - please try to dump `posts_request` filter if you need query that is run to retrieve posts.